# How to save a core-data model url attribute

Tags: swift, core-data

I have an app where a user can add website urls, save and display the sites. I want o be able to store and fetch with core-data

Comment: That's a pretty broad question. :) What have you tried? Do you have some code to show us?

Comment: Here is a link to the sample app. I want to add core data. https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_9_Split_View_Master-Detail_Example

Comment: If you are getting started with Core Data I recommend the following books: Core Data By Tutorials from raywenderlich.com or Mastering Core Data with Swift by Bart Jacobs.  I suggest getting electronic copies directly from the authors to get updates.  Regarding your question I note that URI is a native core data "attribute" type.  As part of setting up Core Data you'd design an "entity" (data structure) which would include the URI "attribute".  You'd have Xcode create a NSManagedObject subclass based on the entity.  Then a bunch of work "setting up the core data stack" (requires tutorial books)

Comment: Thanks Darrell. I have followed your instructions, but I can't figure out how to load the url attribute with cellForRowAt indexPath